# React useState not rendering with objects

Tags: reactjs

The Button Component has a event listener onClick which calls changeTheme(). The Content component is a div with some text which is passed a theme prop 'style'. When I click the button, the theme is changed for 2 consecutive clicks. After that no matter how many times I click the button, theme doesn't change.Why is that?

```
function ParentElement() {
    const dark={
            color:'white',
            backgroundColor:'darkgray',
        }
    const light={
            color:'darkgray',
            backgroundColor:'white'
        }

    const [currentTheme,setTheme]=useState(light)

    function changeTheme(e){
        //toggle theme
        currentTheme==light?setTheme(dark):setTheme(light)
    }
    return (
        
        <div>
            <Button changeTheme={changeTheme}/>
            <Content style={currentTheme} />
        </div>
    )
}

function Content({style}) {
    return (
        <div style={style}>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stops working after two times because you are comparing object references, which are changing after the call to `setState`.

Since *currentTheme* is initialized to *light*, the first call to `currentTheme == light ? setTheme(dark) : setTheme(light)` goes in "the true branch" and sets currentTheme to dark. However *setTheme* — as any change of state object in React — returns a new object reference, so from this point onwards *currentTheme* reference will be different from the reference of light or even of dark, although at this point the theme is dark.
Therefore, from now the condition always go in "the false branch", which sets the theme to light.
In JavaScript, a comparison of objects as you are doing is a comparison of references.
You can fix the issue by e.g. comparing the theme name (a string), as it will be a comparison *by value*:

```
function ParentElement() {
    const dark = {
        name: 'dark',
        style: {
            color: 'white',
            backgroundColor: 'darkgray'
        }
    }
    
    const light = {
        name: 'light',
        style: {
            color: 'darkgray',
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        }
    }

    const [currentTheme, setTheme] = useState(light)

    function changeTheme(e) {
        //toggle theme
        currentTheme.name === light.name ? setTheme(dark) : setTheme(light)
        console.log(currentTheme);
    }
    
    return (

        <div>
            <Button changeTheme={changeTheme}/>
            <Content style={currentTheme.style} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but I don't understand how? In my code, lets say 'const dark' is stored in a location A and 'const light' is stored in a location B. 'currentTheme' has the same location as that of 'const light' initially => B. Now after click I check if currentTheme===light which is true. So new state of 'currentTheme' is dark which  points to location A. Similarly in the next click it points to B and so on right? So the state is changing with each click. Then why is it not rendering and why is renders for first two clicks. Kindly help.

Comment: Ok I'll add more details on why it always sets the light theme after setting once the dark theme.

Comment: Please see the added explanation

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation :). So when I say setTheme(light), it doesn't point to const light but creates a new object in memory right?

Comment: It uses the _light_ object as the source object to set the state, but it returns a new object and assigns it to _currentTheme_. Therefore _currentTheme_ "looks like" the light object, but it is a different object.

Comment: When a functional component re-renders, locally declared objects are re-created, old are freed. In a class component, a re-rendering triggers the render method, plus other lifecycle methods (e.g. `componentDidUpdate`). But the constructor of a class component, or the method `componentDidMount`, are not called again when that component is re-rendered.

Comment: Though if the themes would have been declared outside the component, none of this would have been a problem in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this way and archive this.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const themes = {
  dark: {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: "darkgray"
  },
  light: {
    color: "darkgray",
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }
};

function ParentElement() {
  const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = useState("light");

  const changeTheme = (e) => {
    //toggle theme
    const newThemeMode = themeMode === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    setThemeMode(newThemeMode);
  };

  const currentTheme = useMemo(() => {
    return themes[themeMode];
  }, [themeMode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeTheme}>change Theme</button>
      <Content style={currentTheme} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you would like to understand what is actually happening here:

`light` is an `object`. When you set the default theme by `useState(light)` react sets a reference to the `light` object.

In your `changeTheme` handler, you are checking if the `currentTheme` and `light` are referencing the same object `currentTheme==light`, you are not checking if they are similar. That is in fact a huge difference here. On the first click, the outcome is true and the theme switches to dark.

On the second click, the theme switches to light but this time react is deep copying the `light` object under the hood. The reference to the light object is lost. Every time you check for `currentTheme==light`, the outcome will be false from now on, and the theme will never switch to dark again.

To solve this, you would have to make a deepEqual check (not recommended) or introduce another flag or variable to track the currently selected theme.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So on every render react deep copies all objects declared in the file?

Comment: no, not all objects are deep copied. It is only the setter for the state variable `setTheme`  which is causing the confusion here. It is deep copying the theme object, that you are passing in there.

Comment: In fact, it is a shallow copy. So if you would have nested objects, the reference of those nested objects would remain the. But the reference for the root object is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Reacts useState hook sets state asynchronous, which means it won't do it immediately. In this case, when you might want to use the useState callback. So try this:

```
currentTheme === light ? setTheme(() => dark) : setTheme(() => light)
```

I would also consider doing the check for current theme with the help of the callback, to make sure you compare with the actual state, like so:

```
setTheme((prevTheme) => prevTheme === light ? dark : light)
```

What I've learned is that when you want to modify your state based on the previous one, you want to take the previous state from the statehook callback, which makes sure you get the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

first `light` will always be true since `Boolean({})` will always resolve to true... you need to to check for example `themes[key]` and toggle based on that